vstest with workload identity federation
I'm using DevOps Pipelines to run my sql unit tests.
This works well with the vstest task and a service connection with ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal.
But our platforming guy changed the authentification mode in the service connection to workload identity federation.
Since this change, it is not longer possible to connect to our azure cloud database.
If I change the authentification in the app.config of the test app, the error is:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured.
I tried different settings in the connection string in the app.config. I also tried to replace the vstest task to an azureCLI task where I call the test via vstest.console.exe. Here it is possible to generate an accesstoken but I don't know how I pass this to the tests.
Till now I can't find a solution for my connection problem.
Does anyone have the same setup or knows how to solve this?
Added: The yaml of the old VSTEST task:
steps:
- task: VSTest@3
  displayName: 'run DB Unittest'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*Tests.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
    codeCoverageEnabled: true

Added: The yaml of the new AzureCLI task:

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ServiceConnection'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     $Result      = "$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults" 
     $TestDLL     = ".\...\Tests.dll"
     $TestAdapter = ".\...\TestAdapter.dll"
     $TetPlatform = "...\vstest.console.exe"
     
     &$TetPlatform $TestDLL /TestAdapterPath:$TestAdapter /ResultsDirectory:$Result
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
  enabled: false

Added: The connection part of the OLD app.config:
<configSections>
  <section name="SqlUnitTesting" type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.Configuration.SqlUnitTestingSection, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, Version=19.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***" />
</configSections>
    <SqlUnitTesting>
<DataGeneration ClearDatabase="true" />
<ExecutionContext Provider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
                  ConnectionString="Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;
                                    Persist Security Info=False;
                                    Pooling=False;
                                    Multiple Active Result Sets=False;
                                    Connect Timeout=60;
                                    Encrypt=True;
                                    Trust Server Certificate=False;
                                    Data Source=#{UTConnectionDataSource}#;
                                    Initial Catalog=#{UTConnectionInitialCatalog}#;
                                    User ID=#{UTConnectionUserID}#;
                                    Password=#{UTConnectionPassword}#;"
                  CommandTimeout="30" />
<PrivilegedContext Provider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
                  **same as above**
 />
    </SqlUnitTesting>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" description="Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider for SqlServer" type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>

Connection string of the NEW app.config
ConnectionString="Authentication=Active Directory Workload Identity;
                                            Persist Security Info=False;
                                            Pooling=False;
                                            Multiple Active Result Sets=False;
                                            Connect Timeout=60;
                                            Encrypt=True;
                                            Trust Server Certificate=False;
                                            Server=#{UTConnectionDataSource}#;
                                            Database=#{UTConnectionInitialCatalog}#;
                                            User ID=#{UTConnectionUserID}#;
        "
                          CommandTimeout="30" />

the error message when I use the OLD connection string with workload identity:
Initialization method ModulverbinderTests.CreateDMC.TestInitialize threw exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Application with identifier '' was not found in the directory
''. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.
You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.


Please share the yaml file of your DevOps pipeline and related info in your app.config. 2. What's the error in your pipeline debug logs before you change the authentication in the app.config?


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT for sure, I added the old VSTEST task, the new AzureCLI task and the old app.config (I didn't copy the assemblyBinding part, as it shouldn't matter here)


"But our platforming guy changed the authentification mode in the service connection to workload identity federation." - Where did he change the authentication mode? In the service connection from Project Settings? But the VSTest@3 task does not have any input for the service connection parameter.  How did you use this service connection before? 2. What's the result if you create a new service connection and use the original authentication mode?



-> I will foreward this question. And yes, thats true, VSTEST@3 uses the given connection string.
I have added the error in the question


I would like to clarify that this issue has nothing to do with Azure DevOps. 1. The VSTest@3 task does not need to use any service connection. The authentication information used in your project is not passed in from Azure DevOps but is defined in your project. If you test your project locally, you will have the same issue.


About "our platforming guy changed the authentification mode in the service connection to workload identity federation." - When you created an ARM service connection in Azure DevOps, you used a service principal to authenticate with an app registration in Azure Tenant. Now you use workload identity federation as the authentication method with your app registration. What actually changed is the authentication method of the app registration in your Azure Tenant. And your project accesses your SQL DB through this app registration.


You can check this doc Workload identity federation to understand how it works and configure it in your app registration.

According to your app.config, you are using ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal as the authentication.
But according to Connect to Azure SQL with Microsoft Entra authentication and SqlClient, you should use Active Directory Workload Identity.

Available starting in version 5.2, like with managed identities, workload identity authentication mode uses the value of the User Id parameter in the connection string for its Client Id if specified. But unlike managed identity, WorkloadIdentityCredentialOptions defaults its value from environment variables: AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, and AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE. However, only the Client Id may be overridden by the connection string.

The following example demonstrates Active Directory Workload Identity authentication with a user-assigned managed identity with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v5.2 onwards.
// Use your own values for Server, Database, and User Id.
// With Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v5.2+
string ConnectionString = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Workload Identity; Encrypt=True; User Id=ClientIdOfManagedIdentity; Database=testdb";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
}


sorry, I mixed the requested data. instead of posting the error message with the old app.config, I posted the old app.config :(
I use the Active Directory Workload Identity in the connection string of the new app.config ;)
I added the new connection string and the error message of the old one in my question
